# Lista de inscritos de um canal do YouTube

Tags: youtube-api

Existe alguma forma onde eu possa criar uma lista em HTML com os inscritos de um canal usando as API´s do YouTube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lista é grande:
[Neste link é a API do Youtube](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/)

Tem esse termo:
`youtube.activities.list`, que retorna todos os eventos de um canal.

Dar uma estudada em como funcionam as requisições à API, mas em uma olhada rápida, o início é por aí.

Comment: Dê um upvote na minha pergunta para que eu possa conseguir também fazer o mesmo por você

Comment: @Luciano mas ele não precisa dar upvote na pergunta para que você possa dar upvote na resposta

Comment: @Luciano upvote não é obrigação e não tem relação com aceitar uma resposta como correta, mais detalhes em [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635)

Comment: Sei disso amigo, mas pra votar tenho que ter ao menos 15 de reputação. Por isso pedi pra conseguir isso. Eu estava com 13 de reputação.